# Keycloak + oauth2-proxy; how to get "id_token_hint"

Tags: angular, nestjs, keycloak, oauth2-proxy

I use keycloak with oauth2-proxy behind a nginx server. The complete authenication flow is handled by this free tools.
So my *Angular* frondend and *NestJS* backend got the access-request-token in the request header, but the authentication is completly handled by oauth2-proxy and keycloak.

Now I need the `id_token`/`id_token_hint`. The only way to get this is to use the url:
`http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token` with the **scope: openid**. (For your information: I **don't** use grant_type *authorization_code*, because the complete authentication flow goes over keycloak + oauth2-proxy. My backend/frontend never send a login/auth request directly)

[image]

This works very well and I get a id_token. The problem: If I use this id_token for the keycloak (18+) logout process the *logout confirm dialog* will be shown. Problem: the request create a new keycloak client session.

Is it possible to get the **id_token** for a clients current session, without creating a new session?

Comment: Here is a disuss for this topic: https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/issues/884 If anyone has the same problem, comment it.. We only can hope that the oauth2-proxy team will add this feature.

Comment: If your Angular frontend triggers logout via NestJS /logout route, and NestJS, retrieving stored ID token and send the logout with Keycloak's logout endpoint, would not work ?

Comment: Problem is: I cannot store the token because the oauth2-proxy is handling the complete login. So I never see the token.

Comment: I don't see the requirement for the `oauth2-proxy`. Why do you need it?

Comment: oauth2-proxy is handling all the token things and the complete login/logout flow. So keycloak show login-screen and oauth2-proxy will manage the tokens (expiring, refreshing and so on) super easy. Additional we can use SSI with google, too - without any code. But... Since few weeks Version 0.7.6. is available and they "solved" my problem! `--backend-logout-url` is now integreated as command line arg and can be used with a special placeholder `{id_token}` to set a special logout url. Thx to oauth2 team!

Comment: Can you post an example of how to use `--backend-logout-url` with Keycloak?

Comment: @seldesjo I have edited the answer below to include an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146085/keycloak-oauth2-proxy-how-to-get-id-token-hint?noredirect=1#comment137851425_78146085), [`oauth2-proxy` v7.6.0](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/releases/tag/v7.6.0) now includes `--backend-logout-url`

It comes from [PR #1876](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/pull/1876)

> ### Session aware logout, backend logout url approach
>
> `--backend-logout-url`: URL to call to perform backend logout, `{id_token}` would be replaced by the actual `id_token` if available in the session

Your issue was the inability to access the `id_token` due to the authentication and session management being entirely handled by `oauth2-proxy`, which stands in front of the application and Keycloak. That arrangement made it difficult to perform actions that require the `id_token`, such as a session-aware logout from Keycloak, without initiating a new session or directly exposing the token to the client application.

The `--backend-logout-url` option allows specifying a URL that `oauth2-proxy` will call to initiate a backend logout process.
Key point: this URL can include a placeholder `{id_token}` which `oauth2-proxy` will automatically replace with the actual `id_token` from the current session. That *dynamic* substitution makes sure the correct token is used without exposing it more broadly or requiring it to be stored client-side.

Since `oauth2-proxy` manages session tokens (including refreshing and expiration), integrating the logout process through this tool makes sure logout requests are inherently aware of the session context. This matches `oauth2-proxy`'s capabilities to manage and invalidate sessions as needed.

By handling token insertion and logout URL calls within `oauth2-proxy`, there is no need for the application to directly manage tokens or implement custom logic for session-aware logouts. That reduces the complexity within the application codebase and enhances security by minimizing the exposure of sensitive tokens.

The ability to specify a backend logout URL that includes the `id_token` allows for direct integration with various authentication providers (like Keycloak) and supports different logout mechanisms, including those requiring tokens for validation. That flexibility ensures broader compatibility and simplifies integration with existing authentication infrastructure.

---

> Can you post an example of how to use `--backend-logout-url` with Keycloak?

Assuming a logout URL for your Keycloak realm, like "`https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout`", when starting `oauth2-proxy`, you will include the `--backend-logout-url` option, formatted to include your Keycloak logout URL and the `{id_token}` placeholder. The `{id_token}` will be replaced by `oauth2-proxy` with the user's actual `id_token` at runtime.

Your `oauth2-proxy` startup command or configuration file would include:

```
--backend-logout-url="https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint={id_token}&post_logout_redirect_uri={post-logout-redirect-uri}"
```

With `{post-logout-redirect-uri}`: the URL to which you want users to be redirected after logout. That URI must be one of the allowed redirect URIs configured in your Keycloak client settings.

Make sure your Keycloak client is configured to accept the post-logout redirect URI you specified. That is done in the Keycloak admin console, under your client's settings, in the "`Valid Redirect URIs`" section.

And `oauth2-proxy` must be configured to store session information, including the `id_token`. That typically involves configuring session storage options like `--cookie-secret` and `--session-store-type`.

A more concrete example command for starting `oauth2-proxy`, including the hypothetical Keycloak logout URL and redirect:

```
oauth2-proxy \
  --cookie-secret=<your-secret> \
  --session-store-type=cookie \
  --provider=keycloak \
  --backend-logout-url="https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint={id_token}&post_logout_redirect_uri=https://myapp.example.com/post-logout"
```

That would instruct `oauth2-proxy` to call Keycloak's logout endpoint, automatically including the `id_token` for the current session and specifying where the user should be redirected after logout.

Comment: @Flo Great! I have added an example in response to [seldesjo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15200475/seldesjo)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146085/keycloak-oauth2-proxy-how-to-get-id-token-hint/78193305?noredirect=1#comment137943714_78146085).